# What is the purpose of having multiple bays for a bowtie antenna?

Tags: antenna, antenna-theory, bowtie

What would be the difference between a two-bay antenna designed like this:
[image]

and a four-bay antenna designed like this:

[image]

Assuming that everything about these two antennas are identical aside from the number of bays, what exactly does "adding more bays" do for a bowtie antenna?

Comment: Welcome.  Please be sure to take the Tour to see how this SE works:  https://ham.stackexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It increases the directionality and gain of the antenna. This helps it reject noise coming from directions other than towards the transmitter. The higher signal to noise ratio leads to better reception.

For this antenna as drawn, the directions of maximum gain are two: one coming out of the page, and one in the opposite direction. Sometimes these antennas will have a reflector behind them to reduce that to just one direction.

For a wave arriving from the maximum gain direction, the wavefront hits all the bowties at the same time. The individual signals received from each bowtie then add constructively.

It's not immediately obvious why there's the crossover in the antenna. That is, why not are all the blue halves on one side, and the reds on the other? The reason is the two outer bowties are farther away from the feedpoint than the inner bowties. If the incoming wave hits all the bowties at the same time, but then the bowties are at different lengths from the feedpoint, by the time the signals have traveled from the bowtie to the feedpoint they will no longer be in phase, and no longer add constructively.

The crossover compensates for this delay. The wave is oscillating with some period; if we wait half this period the polarity at that instant will be reversed. The crossover accomplishes the same thing, not by waiting but by crossing the wires. Meanwhile, the extra distance that must be travelled from the farther bowties introduces another half-period of delay. That half-period, plus the additional half-period of the crossover, means that we are effectively delaying the signal by a full period, which is the same as not delaying it at all.

Comment: It has crossover for the same reason the original  log-periodic antenna does.  In the end it turned out not to matter much so most of what we call log-periodics no longer bother.

Comment: @SDsolar What? Show me an LPDA which doesn't cross over between each element.

Answer (score 0):

I find I learn a lot by reading catalogs, and this was no exception.

Going from [THIS AD FOR BOWTIE ANTENNAS](http://www.solidsignal.com/pview.asp?p=db8) they claim longer range with more bays.

That would make sense because there would be more surface area with which to capture signals.

Obviously, an antenna like your diagram would be bidirectional like any dipole, but the one listed in that ad has a screen reflector on one side to make it unidirectional.

Comment: Just making the antenna bigger doesn't necessarily give it a bigger aperture.

Comment: In the case of a reflector-concentrated (dish) type antenna it does.  I worked with HIPAS, the precursor to HAARP, where we had crossed dipoles standing above a steel mesh, and the total aperture was measured in fractions of an acre.  This antenna is similar.

Comment: A dish antenna is a kind of aperture antenna: the dish is the aperture, less an efficiency factor to account for diffraction, shadowing, resistive losses, etc. The dish is just a mirror. This antenna isn't at all like that: it's a dipole array, and making it bigger will increase the gain only if additional dipoles are added in the right position such that they add constructively.

Comment: OK, I changed my wording.  I didn't mean to spark a debate about whether a screen reflector has an aperture.  My whole point was that the way the sell them is to enhance signal reception in a single direction, and not in two directions like his drawing would do without the reflector.  I like your wording that they add constructively.    But in all my years I have never seen someone erect a free-standing Bowtie like for HF.  In the ad, they are more like driven elements of a 2-element beam, with the reflector being a mesh.  That's all I was trying to say, even though my words were clumsy.

Comment: Meanwhile, think of HAARP.  Crossed dipoles above a flat steel mesh.  They do call the total size the aperture and it is measured in acres.  It is a phased array at HF, and a beautiful thing to behold.  Just like the AESA antennas of the SPY-1 radars on Aegis ships.  Yes, there are thousands of antenna elements but the entire antenna structure's capture area is called the aperture.

Comment: The aperture is just another way to express gain: $(G \lambda^2)/(4\pi) = A$. While it's generally true that a higher gain requires a larger antenna, you can't just arbitrarily make an antenna bigger and say it has a larger aperture. Nor does the cross-sectional area seen from the transmitter need to relate to the aperture. For example, an endfire array does not have "more surface area with which to capture signals", and yet its gain, and thus its aperture, is much larger than an individual element.

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II "The aperture is just another way to express gain" Exactly!  The word *aperture* confuses a lot of folks, because it implies size apart from gain.

Comment: I'm glad we agree. My issue is "That would make sense because there would be more surface area with which to capture signals" which suggests there is a direct relationship between surface area and gain. A common misconception: for example who as a kid didn't think the longer a wire was, the more signal it would pick up?

Comment: I agree with what all you guys are saying, by the way.  No doubt that really is the answer to the OP.  However, let me also point out that in SAR (synthetic aperture RADAR) the aperture is not to create gain but to enhance the perspective view.  Similar with phased-array systems.  It isn't gain so much as focus.  But it takes a large aperture to be able to achieve the proper phasing relationships that are effective.  In this post I really meant capture area - which does indeed properly translate to gain.  I particularly appreciate @Phil's use of real math to describe it.  +1